Which is the Theorem to demonstrate positivity in a system of nonlinear ODEs?
Let
$X'(t) = f(X), 
X(0) = X_0$
be a system of nonlinear ODEs with a positive initial condition, and f is Lipschitz continuous.
In a forum, I read that whenever $f_i(X) \ge 0$ if $X_i = 0,$ for all $i=1, ..., n$ (the dimension of the system), then $X_i(t) \ge 0$ for all $i, t$.
Is it a consequence of Bonis-Brezis theorem or is there another theoretical result demonstrating it?  Can you provide details of the publication of this or a similar result?
Thank you

Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please use mathjax (online TeX)! As to your question: this is a standard result about ODEs. You can prove it quickly under the stronger assumption that $f_i(X) > 0$ whenever $X_i = 0$. Then the result in your statement  follows by approximating $f$.
